# Cypress error in Commands.ts (Argument of type '"login"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Chainable<any>)

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I am trying to use commands.ts to implify repeating actions, like asking for email and password.

but when I try to use this, it gives me the rror for the login(Argument of type '"login"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Chainable)

`

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (email, password) => {
   some codes....
})
```

`

I didn't try anything else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a file index.ts on the same level as commands.ts

put inside

```
export {}
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            login(email:string, password:string): Chainable<void>;
        }
    }
}
```

enjoy

UPDATE - WHY IT WORKS

When we use Typescript everything needs an interface to be described.
In your example, Cypress has its Chainable interface but you wish it to have a 'login' property too.
With this code, you are saying that you want to extend 'Cypress.Chainable' to have a login property.

Let me explain it to you with another real example

```
interface String {
  myOwnChainableFunction: Function
}

String.prototype.myOwnChainableFunction = function (this: string){
console.log(this)
}

'ciao'.myOwnChainableFunction();
```

In this example, we are extending the String prototype to accept our own function in chain.
In Javascript, we have just to attach it to the prototype but with .ts the Typescript checker pretends this property exists in the String interface, so we added it to the interface too.

Comment: That works thank you, but can you explain me this please ?

Comment: Hi @Matti, I've updated the answer, let me know if it's clear now.

Comment: Thank you @KMaster, after doing the changes,  got not another error in commands.ts in the email,password

parameter) email: Parameters<Cypress.ChainableMethods<any>[T]>[0]
Argument of type '(this: Context, email: Parameters<ChainableMethods<any>[T]>[0], password: Parameters<ChainableMethods<any>[T]>[1]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CommandFn<"login">'.ts(2345)

Comment: have you tried with this?

`export {}
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            login(email:string, password:string): Chainable<void>;
        }
    }
}`

if you need help try to give me an example on StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wxhvwl?file=index.ts

you can save it and share it